# Security against sharing my app

Tags: android, security

I have a simple question as to how  can we **prevent the user to share an apk file** from his/her device to others.Like if i put a paid application in the market and a user downloads it . If its downloaded how can i be sure that he **doesn't transfer the application**  to other or puts it in some third party market . I need to find some security measure to do it for my application.Is there any *permissions*  that needs to be added or any third party security .

All the answers are appreciated.

As I came across [this](http://www.necronet.info/2011/12/hacking-android-lvl-cracking.html) link. How can i prevent LVL

Comment: Have you checked through this already? (http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)

Comment: As Ken said licencing can does the task until someone didn't play with your APK. But there is no any 100% surety about your APK will be safe from these malicious actions....

Comment: Until the industry comes up with a way to prevent stealing software (if ever!), learn to live with the fact that the world is full of thieves and freetards who will steal a $2 application.  There is nothing you can do (you can make investments to make it more difficult but you cannot stop it) so focus on your real users, your value proposition and why honest people would want your app.  Karma man.  Karma!

Comment: Thanks for the Reply @ken Wolf thanks a lot for the link.But is there any mean by which if the user shares the apk with others we could jus tamper the apk that has been transferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Licensing Manager is what you should use which can be found at http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html.

This uses some code that you can put at the start of your application that uses the licensing API to check that your app is licensed. This is done by checking that the account that the user is using on their device has paid for the app via Google Wallet and that a refund has not provided. If it is found to have been paid, then you can let the app run, otherwise you can display an error to the user informing them that it is not licensed. Most apps that do this provide a button that will launch the play store at your app to let them download the legit version.

This doesn't directly stop users copying the APK or publishing it on other markets but it ensures that app cannot be used unless has been purchased by the current user on the Google account they are using.

Although there may be ways to circumvent this check but this is probably the best and most reliable way.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like verify user on your server when app launched, but you cannot force user not to share .apk by technical means. Apk can be easily copied from non-rooted device, and there's absolutely impossible to prohibit user to copy .apk from rooted device even if Google adds some copy protection in future.

Comment: :But Can we tamper the apk after its transferred or make it unusable

Comment: AFAIK, unusable apk = unusable app, because all your classes and resources stored only in apk

Comment: that's what i want it to happen ,so no easy track to get the usage of the apk

Comment: I meant that you cannot change apk on device of user that purchased it, because it will make app useless. But also you cannot change apk when user copy it, because your app can't even know that it was just copied. Look at Boardy's answer, I didn't tried what he suggests, but it looks like what you want.

Comment: Yes, but even then when i get the other user credentials how can we as developers make the application not work as expected or like anything like windows OS thats checks whether the user is using having the right key if not valid degrades the performance of the OS over a period of time

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're asking about how to know if user is purchaser of your app or not? If so, Boardy wrote about it, I'd check his suggestions first. If you want to know how to implement different behaviors for purchased app and copied app, I think, operator `if` will help you.

Comment: from the solution given by Boardy & Ken Wolf i'll only get the user who is using my application even i can get to know whether he has purchased the application from the play store or not but how can i as a developer stop him from using the application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31768/discussion-between-terril-thomas-and-spongebobfan)